# Render form after method completion in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I am facing a problem with my page with VueJS. It's a page for different translations of the website. It has a dropdown on the top for the language selection that once switched will update the fields with the current language.

The problem starts when it loads, because my form is like this:

```
<form id="trForm">
    ...
    <input type="text" name="header_title" class="form-control" v-model="translations.header.header_title" />
    ...
</form>
```

It's trying to access these  attributes before the method returns any data, but somehow it will still show the data once it is complete, but it becomes troublesome when I try to switch the language, it won't because of this problem and also, if I do the following:

```
<form id="trForm">
    ...
    <input type="text" name="header_title" v-if="translations.header" class="form-control" v-model="translations.header.header_title" />
    ...
</form>
```

on each field, those that aren't populated will display no field at all for a new input value. I tried something like `translations.features || ''`, but no success.

I also tried to put on the parent block a condition that if the loading is false will display the form, but since the page is loaded first than the method is executed, it will always be false for the first microsecond.

```
methods: {
    fetchTranslations(e) {
        let vm = this;
        vm.loaded = false;
        $.get('/ajax/admin/translations', { 'locale': e }).done((data) => {
            if (data.success) {
                vm.translations = JSON.parse(data.translations.translation);
                vm.loaded = true;
            } else {
                toastr.error('Something went wrong');
            }
        });
    },
```

Please, what do I do? It'd be good to show the form after there is data.

Comment: I18n is hard. I can highly recommend http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/en/

Comment: I don't want to do it with VueJS. I just want to show the form after there are data to be displayed.

Comment: My bad, totally misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Introduce a new variable, e.g. `loaded` that defaults to `false`
- Use this variable as a `v-if` condition on the `form`
- In the callback of your data fetch, set `loaded` to `true`.

Comment: Almost. The first load works, but when I switch the language it will display the same error. When switching language, the same method is ran, passing a parameter.

Comment: You could always set `loaded` to `false` whenever the language is changed and back to `true` when the load is completed - e.g. via `watch` on `translations`

Comment: Can you please write an example? I will update the question with the VueJS method.

Comment: I'd usually be happy to but it's way past my bedtime. Here's a link to get you started: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property - you essentially want to `watch` `translations` and set `this.loaded` to `false` in the callback.

Comment: Quick correction: you want to watch the property that triggers your fetch of the translations.

Comment: Did some attempts, nothing changed. I watched the `select` input, I could see the new and old values, but setting the variable to false do not help.

Comment: Actually, it was correct. I didn't realize that the stored JSON had empty values, therefore the fields trying to access these empty fields would display the error. Your solution helped, I just updated in the API the JSON format to store either the post data or empty string.